# Prove the formula of the area of a unit sphere $A_d=\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma (d/2)}$

Tags: integration, geometry, analysis, fourier-analysis

Prove the formula 
$$A_d=\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma (d/2)}$$ 
where $A_d$ denote the area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Use polar coordinates and the fact that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-\pi |x|^2}dx=1.$

So I need to find out $\int_{S^{d-1}} d\sigma(\gamma),$ and I think this corresponds to, using spherical coordinates, $\int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi \cdots \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{d-2}\theta_1 \sin^{d-3}\theta_2 \cdots \sin \theta_{d-2}d\theta_{d-1}\cdots d\theta_1.$

I'm trying to prove this exercise following the hint, but I don't know how to derive a the integral of a Gaussian in the first place to compute this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I would expect that *at least* you'd write down the corresponding surface integral...

Comment: A simple google search comes up with [Volume of a n-ball](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) and [N-Sphere wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere).

Comment: Why not use induction?

Comment: How is this related to Fourier analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_d(R)$ be the area of the $d$-dimensional unit sphere with radius $R$.
Obviously $A_d(R) = R^{d-1} A_d$, and by Cavalieri's principle
$$ 1 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(-\pi|x|^2)\,d\mu = \int_{0}^{+\infty}A_d(R) e^{-\pi R^2}\,dR=A_d\int_{0}^{+\infty}R^{d-1}e^{-\pi R^2}\,dR\tag{1}$$
where
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}R^{d-1}e^{-\pi R^2}\,dR = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{d/2-1}e^{-\pi z}\,dz = \frac{\Gamma(d/2)}{2\pi^{d/2}}\tag{2} $$
follows from the integral definition of the $\Gamma$ function. By $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$ A_d = \frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)} \tag{3}$$
as wanted.